# Need to find similar package => device_apps in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins

It's quite a long time since this [deice_apps](https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps) plugin isn't updated.

Also, it's not supported by AGP 8 and since the plugin is not updated for many months, I guess it's not maintained anymore.

So I would like to ask you if is there any similar package available right now with provides similar functionality as the above package does with the latest updates.

I did research on the internet but found nothing so far.